MIT App Inventor. WebViewer not working on RP4
I have an html which displays videofeed from a python script. We were using the MIT App Inventor. The Webviewer component is used on my app to get the feed as well. This works beautifully on my laptop, however, when i try the same thing on the RP4 it doesn't work. Any reasons why and how to fix.
Any help and advice would be appreciated, I am only a beginner so please as much as possible over explain.
PYTHON:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import threading
import time
from flask import Flask, Response, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

class EyeAnalysisServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pupil_center = (320, 240)  # Example pupil center coordinates (middle of the image)
        self.pupil_radius = 100  # Example pupil radius
        self.num_terms = 10  # Number of Zernike terms to compute
        self.wavelength = 0.00065  # Wavelength of light in meters (650nm)
        self.distance = 0.03  # Distance from camera to eye in meters

    def analyze_frame(self, frame):
        zernike_moments = self.compute_zernike_moments(frame)
        defocus = zernike_moments[1] if len(zernike_moments) > 1 else 0
        astigmatism = zernike_moments[3] if len(zernike_moments) > 3 else 0
        spherical_power = self.diopter_from_defocus(defocus)
        cylindrical_power = self.diopter_from_astigmatism(astigmatism)

        return spherical_power, cylindrical_power

    def compute_zernike_moments(self, image):
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        mask = np.zeros_like(gray)
        cv2.circle(mask, self.pupil_center, self.pupil_radius, 255, -1)

        y, x = np.indices(gray.shape)
        rho = np.sqrt((x - self.pupil_center[0])**2 + (y - self.pupil_center[1])**2) / self.pupil_radius
        theta = np.arctan2(y - self.pupil_center[1], x - self.pupil_center[0])

        zernike_moments = []
        for n in range(self.num_terms):
            for m in range(-n, n+1, 2):
                z = self.zernike(n, m, rho, theta)
                moment = np.sum(z * gray * mask)
                zernike_moments.append(moment)

        zernike_moments = np.array(zernike_moments)
        norms = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.abs(zernike_moments) ** 2))
        zernike_moments /= norms if norms != 0 else 1

        return zernike_moments

    def zernike(self, n, m, rho, theta):
        if (n - abs(m)) % 2 != 0 or abs(m) > n:
            print(f"Unsupported combination: n={n}, m={m}")
            return 0  

        if m > 0:
            return np.sqrt(2 * (n + 1)) * self.zernike_radial(rho, n, m) * np.cos(m * theta)
        elif m < 0:
            return np.sqrt(2 * (n + 1)) * self.zernike_radial(rho, n, abs(m)) * np.sin(abs(m) * theta)
        else:
            return self.zernike_radial(rho, n, 0)

    def zernike_radial(self, rho, n, m):
        if (n - abs(m)) % 2 != 0 or abs(m) > n:
            return 0

        pre_sum = 0
        for k in range((n - abs(m)) // 2 + 1):
            pre_sum += (-1) ** k * math.factorial(n - k) / \
                       (math.factorial(k) * math.factorial((n + abs(m)) // 2 - k) *
                        math.factorial((n - abs(m)) // 2 - k) * math.factorial(k + abs(m)))
        return pre_sum * rho ** (n - abs(m))

    def diopter_from_defocus(self, defocus):
        if self.wavelength * self.distance != 0:
            return -defocus / (self.wavelength * self.distance * 1000)
        else:
            return np.inf

    def diopter_from_astigmatism(self, astigmatism):
        if self.wavelength * self.distance != 0:
            return -astigmatism / (2 * self.wavelength * self.distance * 1000)
        else:
            return np.inf

eye_analysis_server = EyeAnalysisServer()

def capture_frames():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        spherical_power, cylindrical_power = eye_analysis_server.analyze_frame(frame)

        # Draw the analysis results on the frame
        text = f'Spherical Power: {spherical_power:.2f}, Cylindrical Power: {cylindrical_power:.2f}'
        cv2.putText(frame, text, (0, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (0, 225, 0), 2)

        # Save the frame as "frame.jpg"
        cv2.imwrite("frame.jpg", frame)

        # Wait for a short duration to avoid high CPU usage
        time.sleep(0.1)

@app.route('/video_feed')
def feed():
    return app.send_static_file('frame.jpg')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start the thread to continuously capture frames
    threading.Thread(target=capture_frames, daemon=True).start()

    # Run the Flask app
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)

----
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Eye Analysis</title>


    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
        body {
            scale:50%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
            background: rgb(34, 112, 122);
        }
        .video-container {
            text-align: center;
            background: white;
            box-shadow: 0px 10px 30px #000000;
            height:650px;
            width:650px;
        }
        h1{
            font-family:"Poppins", sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="video-container">
        <h1>EYE ANALYSIS</h1>
        <img id="video-feed" src="frame.jpg" alt="Video Feed">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

